Katalon Studio : Getting 400 Bad Request if using variables, but fine with hard coded values
I m able to execute PUT request successfully when hard coding the values.

But getting BAD Request when trying to dynamically set the values via variables

By the way getting this error at the backend for above request
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value"

Where is ucdId defined?
